# Can Haskell inline functions passed as an argument?

Tags: haskell, optimization

Let's say I pass a small function `f` to `map`. Can Haskell inline `f` with `map` to produce a small imperative loop? If so, how does Haskell keep track of what function `f` really is? Can the same be done with Arrow combinators?

Comment: Inlining is a really simple syntactic mechanism (iteratively replacing left-hand sides with right-hand sides of functions), there is no "keeping tack of what `f` is". Certainly if  you have `map f` in your code somewhere then `map` may be inlined at that callsite, at which point `f` also could be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `f` is passed in as an argument, then no, probably not. If `f` is the name of a top-level function or a local function, then probably yes.

```
foobar f = ... map f ...
-- Probably not inlined.

foobar = ... map (\ x -> ...) ...
-- Probably inlined.
```

That said, I gather that most of the performance difference between inline and out of line comes not from the actual inlining itself, but rather from any additional subsequent optimisations this might allow.

The only way to be "sure" about these things is to actually write the code, actually compile it, and have a look at the Core that gets generated. And the only way to know if it makes a difference (positive or negative) is to actually benchmark the thing.

Comment: In the first case, `foobar` itself could easily be inlined, allowing `f` to be inlined as well.

Comment: Depends how much stuff `foobar` does in addition to calling `f` &mdash; but yes, it's certainly possible it will be inlined. The only way to really know is to look.

Answer (score 11):

The definition of the Haskell language does not mandate a Haskell implementation to inline code, or to perform any kind of optimization. Any implementation is free to apply any optimization it may deem appropriate.

That being said, Haskell is nowadays often run using GHC, which does optimize Haskell code. For inlining, GHC uses some heuristics to decide whether something should inlined or not. The general advice is to turn optimization on with `-O2` and check the output of the compiler. You can see the produced Core with `-ddump-simpl`, or the assembly code with `-ddump-asm`. Some other [flags](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/options-debugging.html) can be useful as well.

If you then see that GHC is not inlining stuff you would like to, you can provide a hint to the compiler with `{-# INLINE foo #-}` and [related pragmas](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#inline-noinline-pragma).

Be wary of mindlessly applying optimizations, though. Often, programmers spend their time to optimize parts of the program which have a *negligible* impact to the overall performance. To avoid this, it is strongly recommended to [*profile*](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/profiling.html) your code first, so that you know where your program spends a lot of time.

Comment: This is useful advice, but it doesn't actually answer the question as asked.

Comment: The great thing about working on libraries is that I typically have no way to know which functions my users will use in performance-sensitive places, so I can safely spend time optimizing (almost) anything.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example where GHC does inline a function passed as an argument :

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import qualified Data.Vector as V

plus :: Int -> Int -> Int
plus = (+)

sumVect :: V.Vector Int -> Int
sumVect = V.foldl1 plus
```

`plus` is passed as the argument of `foldl1`, which results in summing a vector of integers. In the Core, `plus` is inlined and optimized to the unboxed `GHC.Prim.+# :: Int# -> Int# -> Int#` :

```
letrec {
          $s$wfoldlM_loop_s759
            :: GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int#
          $s$wfoldlM_loop_s759 =
            \ (sc_s758 :: GHC.Prim.Int#) (sc1_s757 :: GHC.Prim.Int#) ->
              case GHC.Prim.tagToEnum# @ Bool (GHC.Prim.>=# sc_s758 ww1_s748)
              of _ {
                False ->
                  case GHC.Prim.indexArray#
                         @ Int ww2_s749 (GHC.Prim.+# ww_s747 sc_s758)
                  of _ { (# ipv1_X72o #) ->
                  case ipv1_X72o of _ { GHC.Types.I# y_a5Kg ->
                  $s$wfoldlM_loop_s759
                    (GHC.Prim.+# sc_s758 1#) (GHC.Prim.+# sc1_s757 y_a5Kg)
                  }
                  };
                True -> sc1_s757
              }; }
```

That's the `GHC.Prim.+# sc1_s757 y_a5Kg`. You can add simple artihmetic inside function `plus` and see this Core expression expand.